Azure DevOps REST API: Permissions Not Updating Despite Successful Response
Question:
I am trying to update permissions for a pipeline in Azure DevOps using the REST API, but although I get a 204 No Content response, the permissions are not actually being applied or updated.
What I'm Doing:
I'm using the Azure DevOps REST API to update the Access Control Entries (ACL) for a specific pipeline. Below is the POST request payload I am using:
`permissions_payload = {
  "value": [
    {
      "inheritPermissions": False,
      "token": "vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/{project_id}/{pipeline_id}",
      "acesDictionary": {
        "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-1204400969-2402986413-2179408616-0-0-0-0-1": {
          "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-1204400969-2402986413-2179408616-0-0-0-0-1",
          "principalName": "[{project_name}]\\Contributors",
          "allow": 0,
          "deny": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

# POST request
response = requests.post(
    permission_url,
    headers=headers,
    json=permissions_payload,
    verify=False
)

if response.status_code == 200 or response.status_code == 204:
    print("Permissions updated successfully.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to update permissions: {response.status_code}")`

Response:
I receive a 204 No Content, indicating the request was successful.
However, when I check the pipeline's security settings via the Azure DevOps UI, the permissions are not updated.
Steps I've Tried:
Checked the descriptor: I'm using the correct descriptor for the "Contributors" group retrieved from the Graph API.
Verified the token: The token I'm using follows the format:
vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/{project_id}/{pipeline_id}
Tried both inheritPermissions: True and inheritPermissions: False, but the outcome is the same.
My Goal:
I want to deny certain permissions for the "Contributors" group on a specific pipeline, but nothing seems to work despite receiving a successful response from the API.

You can change the token value to  "token": "{project_id}/{pipeline_id}", in permissions_payload and check if it can work. Or you can change to use the Rest API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access-control-entries/set-access-control-entries?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP to set the pipeline permission. For more detailed info, you can refer to my answer.

Based on your description, you need to use Rest API to update the Pipeline permissions.
To meet your requirement, you can use the Rest API: Access Control Entries - Set Access Control Entries
Update Pipeline permission SecurityNamespaceId : 33344d9c-fc72-4d6f-aba5-fa317101a7e9
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrolentries/33344d9c-fc72-4d6f-aba5-fa317101a7e9?api-version=6.0

Request Body:
{
    "token":"{ProjectID}/{PipelineID}",
    "merge":true,
    "accessControlEntries":[{
        "descriptor":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-491114055-2098815309-2189422963-3385397751-1-479303010-554652490-2991085287-3350433821",
        "allow":16384,
        "deny":16
    }]
}

To get the descriptor ID, you can use the Rest API: Identities - Read Identities
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=[{project_name}]\Contributors&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.0

Python Script sample:
import requests
import json

url = "https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/accesscontrolentries/33344d9c-fc72-4d6f-aba5-fa317101a7e9?api-version=6.0"

payload = json.dumps({
  "token": "{ProjectID}/{PipelineID}",
  "merge": True,
  "accessControlEntries": [
    {
      "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-491114055-2098815309-2189422963-3385397751-1-479303010-554652490-2991085287-3350433821",
      "allow": 16384,
      "deny": 16
    }
  ]
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic {Base64PAT}'

}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

if response.status_code == 200 or response.status_code == 204:
    print("Permissions updated successfully.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to update permissions: {response.status_code}")

print(response.text)

Permission value list:
Administer build permissions: 16384

Delete build pipeline: 4096

Delete builds: 8

Destroy builds: 32

Edit build pipeline: 2048

Edit build quality: 2

Edit queue build configuration: 65536

Manage build qualities: 16

Manage build queue: 256

Override check-in validation by build: 8192

Queue builds: 128

Retain indefinitely: 4

Stop builds: 512

Update build information: 64

View build pipeline: 1024

View builds: 1

If you need to deny multiple permissions, you can plus related numbers.
For example: deny View builds and View build pipeline permission: 1 + 1024 = 1025
{
.....
"accessControlEntries":[{
    "descriptor":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-491114055-2098815309-2189422963-3385397751-1-479303010-554652490-2991085287-3350433821",
    "allow":0,
    "deny":1025
}]
}

Result:

Update:
If you need to keep using the Rest API and Request body shared in Question: Access Control Lists - Set Access Control Lists, you need to change the token value:
From:
"token": "vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/{project_id}/{pipeline_id}",

To:
"token": "{project_id}/{pipeline_id}",

In this case, it will work as expected too.
